# VB.Net OleDbException "Syntax error in field definition"

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to create a table in an Access database through an OleDbCommand in VB.Net with the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE InTemp (Month DATE, Description TEXT(255), Cost DOUBLE, Patron TEXT(255));
```

The code works fine in Access, but running it in VB.Net returns the OleDbException "Syntax error in field definition".

Full VB code:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " + DatabaseLocale
con.Open()
Dim createInTemp As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE InTemp (Month DATE, Description TEXT(255), Cost DOUBLE, Patron TEXT(255));", con)
createInTemp.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I know there's no problem with the connection as it works elsewhere in my program.

Any help gladly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd stab a guess at `Month DATE` being the problem here, [Month](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/month.php) is a function in MS Access so there's a good chance it's clashing. Try changing your query to

```
CREATE TABLE InTemp ([Month] DATE, [Description] TEXT(255), [Cost] DOUBLE, [Patron] TEXT(255))
```

Also, as far as I am aware `DATE` is a type specific to the app, not necessarily the data store. I would use the actual underyling type which is `DATETIME` (same could be said for `TEXT`).

See [Microsoft Access Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it'd be something dumb like that :P